# serialize obfuscated class C#

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, eazfuscator

I currently have a helper class that I am using to obfuscate a static class that keeps track of high scores in a game I am working on. I am using Eazfuscator on my release and found that when my scores were being serialized, this exception was thrown:

> ArgumentException Identifier ' ' is not CLS-compliant

Is there a way I can store my list of high scores in my helper class and still be able to serialize it after obfuscation?

```
try
{
  GameHighScore highScoreHelper = new GameHighScore();
  highScoreHelper.CreateGameHighScore(highScore);

  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GameHighScore));
  serializer.Serialize(stream, highScoreHelper);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  Logger.LogError("Score.Save", e);
}
```

**My helper class:**

```
  public class GameHighScore
  {
    
    public List<HighScoreStruct<string, int>> highScoreList;

    private HighScoreStruct<string, int> scoreListHelper;

    [XmlType(TypeName = "HighScore")]
    public struct HighScoreStruct<K, V>
    {
      public K Initials
      { get; set; }

      public V Score
      { get; set; }

      public HighScoreStruct(K initials, V score) : this() 
      {
        Initials = initials;
        Score = score;
      }
    }

    public GameHighScore()
    {
      highScoreList = new List<HighScoreStruct<string, int>>();
      scoreListHelper = new HighScoreStruct<string, int>();
    }

    public void CreateGameHighScore(List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> scoreList)
    {

      for (int i = 0; i < scoreList.Count; i++)
      {
        scoreListHelper = new HighScoreStruct<string, int>(scoreList[i].Key, scoreList[i].Value);
        highScoreList.Add(scoreListHelper);
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best solution would be not to obfuscate classes needed for any kind of serialization. You'll gain 2 benefits of doing so:

- no strange names will be used for classes
- re-running obfuscation will not produce new names for the same classes/fields.

Most obfuscators allow to specify attributes that keep particular classes/methods non-obfuscated.

Otherwise - write your own serialization.

Comment: Adding `[Obfuscation(Exclude = True)]` to my struct worked like a charm, the scores are now serializing properly into an xml file. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [`XmlElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx) attribute on your properties.

Comment: +1. This may work and solves problem with name changes. Note that one need to annotate every property.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov That's true. Well, I still don't know why the need of obfuscating public classes, but that's another question.

Comment: Is there a way to tag the structure that is a part of my list so it can be properly serialized through the code obfuscation?

Comment: @NexAddo Hm, good question, I don't know anything like that. But why don't you just use an `[Obfuscation(Exclude = true)]` attribute on your struct, like @Alexei suggested?

Comment: @BalazsTihanyi I guess I was just blanking on what he was saying before. Now that you spelled it out, I remembered System.Reflection had tags like that. Thanks so much. That worked perfectly.